# Boundary values of Cauchy integral along a curve

Tags: holomorphic-functions, cauchy-integral-formula, singular-integrals

I'm studying *J. Duoandikoetxea*'s book *Fourier Analysis*. To provide an example of *standard kernels* he considers the operator $C_\Gamma$ on the Schwartz space $\mathcal{S} (\mathbb{R})$ given by the Cauchy integral
$$
C_\Gamma f(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{f(t)(1+iA'(t))}{t+iA(t)-z}\,dt\,,
$$
where $\Gamma$ is the graph of the Lipschitz function $A(x)$. It is easy to see that this defines an analytic function in $\Omega_+=\{z=x+iy:y>A(x)\}$. However, without any intermediate step, then he claims that the boundary values $\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}C_\Gamma f(x+i(A(x)+\varepsilon))$ are given by
$$
\frac12\left[\,f(x)+\frac i\pi\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\int_{|x-t|>\varepsilon}\frac{f(t)(1+iA'(t))}{x-t+i(A(x)-A(t))}\,dt\right].
$$

I've done some searching on the web and found [this article by Calderón](http://www.mathunion.org/ICM/ICM1978.1/Main/icm1978.1.0085.0096.ocr.pdf)
which does exactly the same without any further explanation, so I'm wondering if I am missing something obvious here.

I would appreciate any help in trying to understand how they arrive at this expression.

Comment: For future readers: He appears to be using a (not for me until now) well known theorem called _Plemelj–Sokthotski_'s formula, from which the given expression for the boundary values follows at once. A suitable and referenced formulation of this can be found in [this article by _Hiroshige Shiga_](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=0ahUKEwiru5KI7eLXAhWr3YMKHZwbCCMQFgg6MAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fjournals.umcs.pl%2Fa%2Farticle%2Fdownload%2F2331%2F1645&usg=AOvVaw0QWdTehTLN3heM6h1uW_bZ).

Answer (score 0):

You can find (quite) a few intermediate steps in [Grafakos, Modern Fourier Analysis]. The proof of Proposition 4.6.1 is what you are looking for.

In practice one has to perform a careful evaluation of the singular integral, because the singularity is on the boundary, i.e. on the Liptschitz curve.